# Multi-thread client socket in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

What's is the change that need to be done to a simple client socket writing in java to became a multi-thread socket .(i took a simple socket examle from the net)
thank you

Comment: Not sure what a simple client socket writing in java is. What is simple?

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "multi-thread socket"? What do you think you can do with a multi-thread socket that you can't do with a "simple" socket?

Comment: @Kenster  i want to parallelize socket streams client side

Answer (score 3):

Multi-thread.. **client** socket? That makes no sense. A single socket is a stream of data, you can't parallelize socket streams like this.

You can of course make an application that opens 5 separate connections (possibly all to the same server, that'd be fine), and processes these 5 separate connections, each consisting of a single stream of 'from client to server' bytes plus a single stream of 'from server to client' bytes, using 5 separate threads.

But you can't write an app that has a single connection, and then tries to process that connection using 5 threads.

Perhaps you meant **server** socket. For server sockets, you create a single `ServerSocket` object. A single thread calls the `accept` method on it (which waits for a client to connect, sets up the connection, and then hands you the `Socket` object that represents the single connection along with the 2 streams that form this connection). You can then make a new thread (or fetch a thread from a pool of threads, that's usually a better way to do this), hand it the socket, and let it deal with that socket. This way, you can have, say, 50 threads, each thread handling one socket: Your server can now deal with 50 clients all connecting simultaneously.

Comment: surely what you described in the first section is what i want. how to proceed to it?

Comment: Just.. make 5 threads. Each thread calls `new Socket(...)`, and does its thing. Your question is akin to asking 'how do I program a word processor'? It is at the same time very simple, and too broad. The answer is: By.. just... doing that.